# certification error while opening SharePoint 2010 site

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, certification

We are getting the certification error while we are trying to open our application. I have no clue on how to proceed on this, any sneak through of my issue with suggestions is appreciated.Please find the image for the error we are facing.

[image]

Comment: Did you add the certificate recently? Did you add it to central admin?

Comment: Hi Christoffer no this was not installed recently we had a admin who did it previously long back. I have no clue if how he did it . This is the first time I am facing it .

Comment: Looks to me it appears to be a self-signed cert (`dev.pdot..`) Import the cert into SharePoint [see link on how to](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Adding-the-Self-Signed-Certificate-in-Manage-trusted-of-SharePoint-2013)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks Like your STS cert having the Broken Chain. Please make sure both STS cert (fedauth.dev.pdot.state.pa.us) and Root Cert both added into the SharePoint.

- You can go to Central admin > Security > Trust
- on this page add all certificates one by one.

Please make sure all the certificate in the chain added in the sharepoint.

[image]

Comment: hi waqas i can see there are certificates alrdy added do i need to delete and add them back?and do i have to add all of them or just adfs related ?

Comment: No, you have to make sure all the certificate should be there...if certificate get change then new certificate should be added. Another thing, browse the site, in browser, on the address bad click on cerrificate icon, it will open the certifcate dialog. from here click on the Certification path, make all the cert listed here should be in SharePoint

Comment: hi waqas sorry for the stupid doubt where do I find the bad click on certificate icon i don't see it..

Comment: check the update answer, i load the image

Comment: You welcome. all the time